# Opening an application from my android application

Tags: android, android-intent

from my application i'm trying to open another one, using this code:

```
package com.copag.lanceappli;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;


public class LanceAppli extends Activity {


    public void LanceAppli() {

           try
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("test.test.test","test.test.test.MainActivity"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            catch( ActivityNotFoundException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch( Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
   public  void main (String [] args) 
   {
       LanceAppli();
   }    
}
```

what happens is that the application crushs... with no error message.

here is what i get:

http://pastie.org/5030644

any ideas?

Comment: i don't have it since i'm deploying directly on the tablet, not using a simulator

Comment: that doesn't matter where you deploy. connect the tablet, set it to enable usb debugging and get the stacktrace. or test it on the simulator.

Comment: all what i get is : The application LanceApplication (process com.copag.LanceAppli) has stoped expectedely. please try again

Comment: go to settings, debug, enable usb debugging, take the usb cable for your tablet, plug it, run adb devices to make sure it is there, if it is not, you may have to add it to a list (google adb + your device name) somewhere, run adb logcat, and you'll have the logcat. and post it here

Comment: @njzk2 i posted the logcat it gives a java.
lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.copag.lanceappli.MainActivity exception

Comment: looks like you use com.copag.lanceappli instead of test.test.test. Do you have such activity, and is it declared in your manifest?

Comment: the two applications had the same activity name, i changed that, and now when i enter on my application nothing happens no error no crush just nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I've tried to use the `intent` directly on the constructor as David said. So I've changed it to:

```
package com.copag.lanceappli;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class LanceAppli extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("test.test.test","test.test.test.MainActivity"));
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch( ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch( Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So I put the code into `onCreate` as it should be and it's working!

Answer (score 2):

If you specify component this means that you use explicit intent. You should not specify in this case category. Try simply:

```
public  void LanceAppli()
{  
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
   intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("test.test.test","test.test.test.MainActivity"));
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

If you need to run Launcher intent then it's better to use the following code:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Comment: Can you try second approach? Moreover, it's possible that activity you try to call cannot be called (because it's not exported). If you can run application with the second approach then the problem is that you have specified packagename and/or activity incorectly.

Comment: i got the package name from the target application manifest file so i don't think it's false

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things broken with the code you've posted:

Your class `LanceAppli` extends `Activity` and you are trying to execute code in the constructor. Don't do this. Activities are instantiated and controlled by the Android OS. You can't instantiate them yourself.

Also, you shouldn't ever provide a constructor for an activity. In any case, when the constructor is called the activity hasn't yet been properly initialized (ie: the `Context` isn't set up yet. This means you cannot do anything that requires a `Context`. In your case you are calling `startActivity()` (which requires a `Context`) in the constructor.

Also, what is the name of the application you are trying to start? Is this application a HOME-screen replacement or a regular Android app?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this and post up a stacktrace if you get one.

```
try
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("test.test.test","test.test.test.MainActivity"));
    startActivity(intent);
}
catch( ActivityNotFoundException e)
{
       e.printStackTrace();
}
catch( Exception e)
{
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: thanks but all what i get is : The application LanceApplication (process com.copag.LanceAppli) has stoped expectedely. please try again

Comment: do you get anything logged in DDMS? It could be the app fails to launch for some other reason.